# Можно ли вызвать функцию асинхронно без использования отдельного потока?

Tags: c++

Можно ли вызвать функцию асинхронно без использования отдельного потока и если да, то как это сделать? Вопрос с собеседования по С++

Comment: В 11 стандарте для этого есть async и фьючерсы. Есть также корутины (boost и в 20 стандарте добавят в язык)

Comment: В \*nix можно через механизм сигналов (но осторожно, есть [подводные камни](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html))

Comment: Можно, для этого ничего не надо (в плане поддержки платформы или библиотек), главное чтобы интерфейс функции поддерживал прерывание / возобновление работы.